# Using a custom Date method I am struggling to create 100 random dates within a range

Tags: java

First and foremost : Homework

Second : We received 90% of this code pre-written from the teacher, we were asked to make some changes to the class itself (implement comparable) as well as doing some small changes(override toString method, create a quicksort method).

The part of the assignment that I am struggling with is the following :

- Use loop and random number generator to create an array of 100 dates in the time
  range from January 1 2018 to December 31 2018.
- Use Quicksort generic method to sort the dates in the array

My code is below.

```
package date;

import java.util.Random;

public class DateQuicksort implements Comparable {

    // variables
    int days;
    String months;
    int years;

    // Constructor without parameters
    public DateQuicksort() {
            this.months = "January";
            this.days = 1;
            this.years = 1000;
    }

    // Constructor with parameters
    public DateQuicksort(int days, String months, int years) {
            super();
            this.days = days;
            this.months = months;
            this.years = years;
    }

    // compareTo method
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DateQuicksort obj = (DateQuicksort) o;
            // logic to compare two Date object
            if (this.getYears() > obj.getYears()) {
                    return 1;
            } else if (this.getYears() < obj.getYears()) {
                    return -1;
            } else {
                    // when same year
                    if (this.getMonths() > obj.getMonths()) {
                            return 1;
                    } else if (this.getMonths() < obj.getMonths()) {
                            return -1;
                    } else {
                            // when same month
                            if (this.getDays() > obj.getDays()) {
                                    return 1;
                            } else if (this.getDays() < obj.getDays()) {
                                    return -1;
                            } else {
                                    // when both date are same
                                    return 0;
                            }
                    }
            }
    }

    // Generic quick sort method
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void qsort(T[] arr, int a, int b) {
            if (a < b) {
                    // variables
                    int i = a, j = b;
                    T x = arr[(i + j) / 2];

                    do {
                            // compare dates
                            while (arr[i].compareTo(x) < 0)
                                    i++;
                            while (x.compareTo(arr[j]) < 0)
                                    j--;

                            if (i <= j) {
                                    T tmp = arr[i];
                                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                                    arr[j] = tmp;
                                    i++;
                                    j--;
                            }

                    } while (i <= j);
                    // recursive call
                    qsort(arr, a, j);
                    qsort(arr, i, b);
            }
    }

    // override tostring method to print dates
    @Override
    public String toString() {
            return monthString(this.getMonths()) + " " + this.getDays() + ", " + this.getYears();
    }

    private static String monthString(int monthNumber) {
            switch (monthNumber) {
            case 1:
                    return "January";
            case 2:
                    return "February";
            case 3:
                    return "March";
            case 4:
                    return "April";
            case 5:
                    return "May";
            case 6:
                    return "June";
            case 7:
                    return "July";
            case 8:
                    return "August";
            case 9:
                    return "September";
            case 10:
                    return "October";
            case 11:
                    return "November";
            case 12:
                    return "December";
            default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad month number!");

            }
    }

    public int getDays() {
            return days;
    }

    public void setDays(int days) {
            if ((days <= 0) || (days > 31)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad day!");
            } else
                    this.days = days;
    }

    public int getMonths() {
            if (this.months.equals("January"))
                    return 1;
            else if (this.months.equals("February"))
                    return 2;
            else if (this.months.equalsIgnoreCase("March"))
                    return 3;
            else if (this.months.equalsIgnoreCase("April"))
                    return 4;
            else if (this.months.equalsIgnoreCase("May"))
                    return 5;
            else if (this.months.equals("June"))
                    return 6;
            else if (this.months.equalsIgnoreCase("July"))
                    return 7;
            else if (this.months.equalsIgnoreCase("August"))
                    return 8;
            else if (this.months.equalsIgnoreCase("September"))
                    return 9;
            else if (this.months.equalsIgnoreCase("October"))
                    return 10;
            else if (this.months.equals("November"))
                    return 11;
            else if (this.months.equals("December"))
                    return 12;
            else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad month!");
            }
    }

    public void setMonths(String months) {
            this.months = months;
    }

    public int getYears() {
            return years;
    }

    public void setYears(int years) {
            if ((this.years < 1000) || (this.years > 9999)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad year!");

            } else
                    this.years = years;
    }


 // main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int count = 0; count < 100; count++) {

            int aDay = 0;
            Random DayGenerator = new Random();
            for(int d=0; d<100; d++){
                aDay = (DayGenerator.nextInt(31)+1);
            }
            int aMonth = 0;
            Random MonthGenerator = new Random();
            for(int m = 0; m < 100; m++) {
                aMonth = (MonthGenerator.nextInt(12)+1);
                DateQuicksort[] newDates = { new DateQuicksort(aDay, monthString(aMonth), 2018)};

                // print date before sort
                System.out.println("Dates before sort :\n");
                for (DateQuicksort date : newDates) {
                        // print
                        System.out.println(date.toString());
                }
                // call sort method
                DateQuicksort.<DateQuicksort>qsort(newDates, 0, newDates.length - 1);

                // after sort
                System.out.println("\nDates After sort :\n");
                for (DateQuicksort date : newDates) {
                        // print
                        System.out.println(date.toString());
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's been a long day, and I am sure there is something really stupid that I am missing or overlooking to get this to do what I want. Right now it's creating a new array and that is caused by the for loop I created. 
Currently my head is gravitating towards making new methods for generating a random day and a random month and then calling those methods in a forloop to insert into the array. Granted, I am much better at walking through these ideas in words, then I am with code.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you need to create a random month, which will then constrain the upper range of the day/date (some months have 30 days, some do not - and leap years :P)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the various functions of Java Date, you find several function setting a value (*setYear* etc), such as described here: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

For all your 100 random values, I would generate a random number in a given range (i.e. for months, a random number from 1 to 12) and set it correspondingly. So, per *one* date you would call *three* times a random number generator.

(Too make it simple, you could either limit it to 1..28 for days, or you need a table or an algorithm determining whether 29,30,31 is valid for that month in that year).

Alternatively, use *setTime* with a random millisec value; which should be in the range you want (calculate millisec for your start date, add a random with a maximum value for your intended time frame)